# How do I populate a tableview with JSON data from Alamofire?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

Before I state my problem, I want to let everyone know that I am new to the coding environment that is Swift, so forgive me for my lack of knowledge. Currently, I am having trouble populating the cells of a tableview using Alamofire based on the data that is returned from a JSON URL. When I run the app in a simulator, data is displayed in the console, but the app crashes with a SIGABRT error. For reference, instead of using a viewcontroller with a tableview element inside, I am using a tableviewcontroller. Here is my code thus far:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var responseArray: NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Alamofire.request("https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/top-songs/all/10/explicit.json").responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print(json)
                self.responseArray = json as! NSArray
            }
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return responseArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "top10", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        let whichSong = responseArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        let artistName = (whichSong as AnyObject)["artistName"] as? String
        cell.textLabel?.text = artistName

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error? What is the full error message in the console?

Comment: are u using Storyboard or XIB ??

Comment: I’m using the storyboard provided in Xcode. As for the error, it seems to be coming from self.responseArray = json as! NSArray. Also, is it required that I reload the data after the json request?

Comment: You're not reloading your table

Comment: unfortunately, adding the reload statement did not fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash occurs because the root object of the JSON is a **dictionary** (represented by `{}`) not an array.

First of all declare a type alias for a JSON dictionary and the data source array as native type, an array of JSON dictionaries:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
var responseArray = [JSONDictionary]()
```

Then parse the JSON and reload the table view, you want probably the array for key `results`:

```
Alamofire.request("https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/top-songs/all/10/explicit.json").responseJSON { response in
      if let json = response.result.value as? JSONDictionary,
         let feed = json["feed"] as? JSONDictionary,
         let results = feed["results"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
             print(results)
             self.responseArray = results
             self.tableView.reloadData()
         }
}
```

Then show the data in `cellForRow`

```
let song = responseArray[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = song["artistName"] as? String
```

Comment: While this got rid of the error, it appears as though nothing is being printed, along with no data being displayed in the tableview

Comment: My bad, there is a root object for key `feed`. I updated the answer.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. Answer updated!

Comment: One more question. How can I use this to load multiple dictionary elements in one cell?

Comment: If you want only to display **one** additional value, use a cell style which provides `detailTextLabel`. Otherwise create a **custom** cell, add `UILabel`s, subclass `UITableViewCell`, set the class of the custom cell to that class, add `IBOutlet`s, connect the outlets to the labels, use the custom cell in `cellForRow` and assign other dictionary values to the labels.

Comment: Again, this worked very well. Thank you for being so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so firstly change

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "top10", for: indexPath)
```

to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "top10")
```

However, with this, `cell` will be `cell?`, you will have to return `cell!`.

Next in your Alamofire response,

```
 if let json = response.result.value {
     print(json)
     self.responseArray = json as! NSArray
     self.reloadData()
     //If above line doesn't work, try tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Why?

The Alamofire request is "asynchronous", meaning it executes codes while your app is doing other things. Therefor, it is likely that you are setting that array after your table is loaded, hence the `reloadData()`

Comment: Don't suggest that. `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` is the recommended API because it returns always a non-optional valid cell. It is not related to the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the below line

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "top10", for: indexPath)
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "top10")
```

Comment: With this change, `cell` is optional and may be `nil`. Additional code needs to be added to check for that and create the cell as needed. This answer is premature until the OP posts more details about the error.

Comment: Don't suggest that. `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` is the recommended API because it returns always a non-optional valid cell.